# Why am I getting a bunch of extra columns when creating a new column with transform()?

Tags: r, lag

I am trying to create a one-year lagged version of a variable `v2elboycot_ord` in `R`. This variable takes a value of 1 if a boycott occurred and 0 otherwise. Here is the code I used to do so:

```
subset$Lagged_boycott<-transform(subset,Lagged_boycott=c(v2elboycot_ord[-1],NA))
```

This gives me a `df` with a bunch of additional columns. What am I doing wrong?

```
structure(list(COWcode = c(70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L), country_name = c("Mexico", 
"Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico"), year = c(1946L, 
1949L, 1952L, 1955L, 1958L, 1961L), v2x_regime = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), v2elboycot_ord = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), v2xel_elecparl = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), v2elintim_ord = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), v2xel_frefair = c(0.062, 0.081, 0.086, 0.091, 0.096, 0.098
), v2xnp_regcorr = c(0.858, 0.858, 0.858, 0.858, 0.858, 0.858
), v2lgcrrpt_ord = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), v2lgfunds_ord = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), v2lgcomslo_ord = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), e_gdppc = c(3.174, 3.568, 4.288, 4.644, 5.121, 5.526)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are you aware that a lagged variable of `v2elboycot_ord` has probably  very little sense in your data set? You are not comparing consecutive years, so I suggest you check how are you going to interpret the results. You don't need `transform`. You can use `data.table` and use something along `subset$lagged_variable = data.table::shift(v2elboycot_ord, -1)`

Comment: Can you please post your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're mixing two interfaces in a way they're not meant to be used. `transform()` returns the whole dataset with modified columns, so you should assign it to your dataset name, not to a column of that dataset. i.e.,

```
subset <- transform(subset, Lagged_boycott = c(v2elboycot_ord[-1], NA))
```

Or, if you want to assign to a column, don't use `transform()`; either index into `subset`...

```
subset$Lagged_boycott <- c(subset$v2elboycot_ord[-1], NA)
```

...or use `with()`:

```
subset$Lagged_boycott <- with(subset, c(v2elboycot_ord[-1], NA))
```

Result from all of these approaches:

```
#> subset[c("v2elboycot_ord", "Lagged_boycott")]
  v2elboycot_ord Lagged_boycott
1              1              1
2              1              1
3              1              1
4              1              1
5              1              0
6              0             NA
```